# How to decode a base64 decoded file and save to a pdf file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using a reporting software which returns me my report in an PDF file as part of a JSON doc in the data event and its base64 encoded. When i take the data i get from the web service and write it to file i get a file which seems to corrupt or so as it does not display the report data.

```
request(options, async(err, resp, body) => {  

var bytes = await base64.decode(body.Data);

fs.writeFile("./Sample.pdf" , bytes , function(err) {
if(err) {
return console.log(err);
 }

console.log("The file was saved!");
});
```

so not sure what i am missing here. I know i got a valid encoded string because i can go to [Free Formatter](https://www.freeformatter.com/) and paste my string and when i click decode and download i have a valid PDF as expected.

Here is a sample of the encoded file which i m trying to decode and save as a pdf..

[Sample encoded string](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mj1iw9jq8o17kaj/sampleEncoded.txt?dl=0)

Comment: Where does `base64` come from? What type is bytes?

Comment: I cant' find any base64 library that returns a promise, please identify which base64 library you are using, or alternatively use "native" node to decode base64, i.e. `var bytes = Buffer.from(body.Data, 'base64');`

Comment: Not sure what you mean Daniel, but my web service returns a json Doc which has a to fields a guid which identifies the request and one called data. So i am setting bytes to the string which returned in my JsonDoc in the Data Element and which is a Base64 encoded string

Comment: Jaromanda, tried the native one with no luck either, this might be less of decode issue then how i write the file as a pdf is not an ascii but binary file

Comment: Is the sample encoded string the contents of Body.data? I can confirm the sample data does decode to a valid pdf.

Comment: Yes, thats the value of the body.Data. So my goal is it to take that string, decode it and save it to a .pdf file so the user can click on it and view it.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error i figured out the issue. When you have a base64 encoded file and you want to save as a binary you do not need to decode the file. you can just tell the fs.writeFile that you have a base64 encoded file and it will do the rest

```
fs.writeFile("./SamplePdf.pdf", body.Data, {encoding: 'base64'}, async(err, data) =>  {
    if (err) {
          console.log('err', err);
          }
          console.log('success');
    });
```